# Convert a Deedle Dataframe into a C# List of Custom Class

Tags: c#, deedle

I receive data from an external API as a Deedle dataframe. I need to take this data and convert it to a List of a custom class to be inserted into a database via Entity Framework.

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction? I've not used Deedle before and am having trouble finding the best way to extract data.

The custom object I need to populate looks like the below:

```
public class FrameData
{
    public string SecurityId { get; set; }
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { set; get; }
    public decimal value { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: automapper will help you for mapping data from api (https://automapper.org/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to get data from a Deedle frame. Does Entity Framework allow you to use interfaces? If so, then there is a nice function `GetRowsAs` which lets you do this:

```
// Given a simple Person interface
public interface Person {
  int Age { get; }
  string Name{ get; }
}

// And a sample data frame with some data
Frame<int, string> df = Frame.FromValues(new[] {
    Tuple.Create(1, "Name", (object) "One"),
    Tuple.Create(2, "Name", (object) "Two"),
    Tuple.Create(1, "Age", (object) 42),
    Tuple.Create(2, "Age", (object) 21)
  });

// You can get an array of rows using 
var rows = df.GetRowsAs<Person>();
```

If Entity Framework cannot handle interfaces, then this method sadly won't work. In that case, you'll need something like:

```
var rows = 
    df.Rows.Select(row =>
      new Person { Name = row.Value.GetAs<string>("Name"), 
                   Age = row.Value.GetAs<int>("Age"))).Observations;
```

Answer (score 0):

What @Tomas Petricek said is a good example, but having to many diffrent classes, this may become a problem.

So here i made an example how to dynamicly convert it to a specific class, and use attribute to mapp between the property and the index of column.

```js
// Mapp a key to an index
public class IndexAttribute: Attribute(){
public int Index { get; private set; }
public IndexAttribute(int index){

Index = index;
}

}

public class FrameData
{
    [IndexAttribute(0)]
    public string SecurityId { get; set; }
    [IndexAttribute(3)]
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    [IndexAttribute(2)]
    public DateTime Date { set; get; }
    [IndexAttribute(1)]
    public decimal value { get; set; }
}

// create a class the convert the frame to class

public static List<T> Convert<T>(this DataTable data) where T: class
{
  var list = new List<T>();
  foreach(var row in data.Rows){
   object item = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
   var props = typeof(T).GetProperties();
   foreach(var p in props){
    var index = p.GetCustomAttribute<IndexAttribute>()?.Index ?? -1;
    if (index< 0)
       continue;
       
      if (table.Columns.length > index) // if the index exist
      {
        var value = row[index]; // get the value.
        if (value == null)
         continue; // ignore null value
        if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(string))
         prop.SetValue(item, value.ToString());
       if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime))
          prop.SetValue(item, DateTime.Parse(value.ToString()));
          
        // .. now check for decimal, int etc
      }
    }
    list.Add(item);
  }
  return list;
}

And now all you need is to call the function

List<Person> persons = df.Convert<Person>(); // that all
```

Comment: Hi Alen, thanks for taking the time to put that together for me.